# Squeak-5.2 can't connect to https://github.com/

Tags: ssl, github, squeak

To repeat: install Squeak-5.2 on Windows (I used Vista because it's what I have)

Open up a Workspace, type:

```
WebClient httpHead: 'https://google.com/'
```

and highlight the expression, hit Alt-P to print the result (it should return a normal HTTP/1.1 response). Repeat the same process for github.com:

```
WebClient httpHead: 'https://github.com/'
```

the two will be different, and at least on my Windows system, fails for github.com, but only that site. Squeak gets as far as telling me: SSL Connect failed with code: -5. The same does not happen under Linux, I get a normal HTTP/1.1 response for github.com.

I have no idea what that code means, nor has my attempts to google the question come up with anything reasonable. Can someone tell me (first off) what on earth that return code means in Squeaks SSL context?

Regards, BrickViking (a.k.a. Dr Smokey)
(Post 1)

Comment: Works on Windows 10. There have been issues with Windows 7 earlier this year, and the fix might not have cured it for Windows Vista. It was about github requiring TLS 1.1 or higher and Windows 7 only did TLS 1.0 with the code in the Squeak SSL plugin before the fix. Here is one of the threads about it, but I do not have a solution ready for you: http://forum.world.st/SSL-error-on-windows-7-td5072637.html#a5072818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find something that worked on my 32-bit Vista, bear in mind that this OS hasn't been supported in over 18 months. [This link](https://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/enable-tls-1.1-and-1.2-on-windows-vista) from John Haller's website refers to an update (KB4056564) than can be applied on Vista that allows Squeak to connect to github.com. I finally found the link when I fed Google with the term "TLS 1.2 Vista".

Regards, BrickViking (a.k.a. DrSmokey)
(Post 2)